# What would you call a person who possesses a certificate?

Tags: nouns

I am building for a client online certification application. Person will complete a short training (few slides) and after that the person will get the certificate proving completion of the "course". How to call that person (preferably one word)?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/416545/17956

Comment: @Jim I am thinking of using *certified* but I was hoping there is better word (noun) for this case.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you avoid "certifiable".

Comment: @HotLicks I did not even considered *certifiable*. This "course" will be so simple anybody who can read in English is *certifiable* :-) I just want to list the people who actually went through the process and finished it.

Comment: My point is that "certifiable" means "insane", and is an insult.  (I gather you understand this, but just in case.)

Comment: One word often use to describe someone who has received certification from a certifying authority is **accredited**. according to Merriam-Webster Online, the verb [_accredit_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accredit) means (1) to give official authorization to or approval of:
(a) to provide with credentials; (b) to recognize or vouch for as conforming with a standard; (c) to recognize (an educational institution) as maintaining standards that qualify the graduates for admission to higher or more specialized institutions or for professional practice ..."  Does that meet your needs?

Comment: @HotLicks I actually didn't know that. Thanks for the info. I probably shouldn't call my client's clients *nuts* :-)

Comment: @SvenYargs I think *accredit* is so far the best option. I think I am going to use that. If you post it as an answer, unless I will get something better in the meantime I will accept it as the right answer.

Comment: Note that _accredited_ is normally used either as an adjective (for example, in "an accredited IT professional") or as a past-tense verb (for example, in "the professional association has accredited Delmore as a journeyman plumber"). There may be some obscure noun form, such as "accreditee," for the person receiving the accreditation —but if so, it is quite rare, and I don't recall ever having seen it used. So if you are looking for a noun (as your question tag indicates), _accredited_ is not a good match.

Comment: How extensive is the certificate? Because there is also the word **licensed**, but it's often used in a significant way. (A license can also be given to somebody who simply pays a fee and meets certain guidelines rather than just passing a course.) Generally, for somebody to be licensed it needs to have some level of universal acceptance.

Comment: Perhaps, “qualified”?

Comment: Certified is like a crazy possibility

Comment: @Kris - "Certified" is exactly what I'd say.  It has the same vague credibility as "Accredited" and "Licensed".

Comment: A **certificate holder**.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of stating the obvious...why not "certified"? If you're licensed to teach a course of say, physical therapy, then a person successfully completing that course would be afforded the title of "Certified Physical Therapist".

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this would be dramatically overstating the certified person's achievements, but within the context of your application or website, you could reasonably refer to them as ***[graduates](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/graduate)***:

> 1: a holder of an academic degree or diploma
>   <sub>*definition from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/graduate)*</sub>

In this case, the "diploma" is merely the certificate that you issued, but that should be clear enough from the context of the application.

Comment: I think it would be too much for my case. As you stated it would be *dramatically overstating the certified person's achievements*. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would really depend on the authorizing organization’s perspective on their authority. Based on what has been said so far, I would prefer the word **”certificant”** or to use the word **”certificated”** as a descriptive adjective before the title of the person being certificated. As pointed out by other posters, certified, even when not being used to mean crazy, has a different connotation than certificated.

Many governing bodies make a definite distinction when it comes to their documents of authorization. The organization with whom I am most familiar is the US FAA. The FAA does not issue airman licenses. They issue certificates for pilot, instructor, examiner, technician, mechanic, etc. When describing an airman, the FAA and its representative will use the term **certificated** (pilot, et. al.) as an adjective. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilot_licensing_and_certification) gives the reason as, “U.S. pilots are certified, not licensed, although the word license is still commonly used informally.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilot_licensing_and_certification) Legally, pilot certificates can be revoked by administrative action, whereas licensing (e.g., a driver's license) requires intervention by the judiciary system.”

Answer (score -1):

Certificated. As obvious as it seems, that is the word used, for example, for teachers  in the U.S. who have earned their teacher's credentials.

Certificated: "a document attesting to the fact that a person has completed an educational course, issued either by an institution not authorized to grant diplomas, or to a student not qualifying for a diploma." Dic.com

Comment: I think you put the definition for *certificate*, and I have never heard the word *certificated* in my life.

Comment: @Micah Windsor 
A random search for "certificated" (There are 1,000 more examples. Look up the word certificated.):       Certificated Employees:

The Certificated division of the Human Resources department is responsible for all personnel transactions for certificated (teaching/credentialed) positions within the r Lucia Mar Unified School District, and directly responsible for compliance with Education Code provisions, collective bargaining agreements, and District policies and procedures.

Comment: I never said it wasn't a word, it's just not as common as *certified*. You also failed to address my first point. *Certificated* is a verb, so its definition cannot begin with *a document*. That is the definition for *certificate*.

Comment: @MicahWindsor Your first point was that I put in the definition for certificate. I didn't. I looked for the definition of "certificated." Your second point was that you had never heard the word "certificated" in your life. I am impressed by that, but as I note above, it is a word, despite your life experience. The OP wanted to know "how to call a person who has completed a course." I suggested  "certificated." It is listed here as an adjective. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/certificated

Comment: From your source: "having an official document as proof that something has happened or been done". That is not the definition you used. And once again, you fail to read the *entirety* of my reply. "I never said it wasn't a word, it's just not as common as *certified*." I know it's a word.

Comment: And if you look at the website where you got your definition closely, you'll notice that the definition is clearly for *certificate*. It says it in big bold lettering at the top of the page.

Comment: @MicahWindsor Well, here are your words from above: "I have never heard the word certificated in my life." If you have never heard the word or looked up its definition (and apparently you can't), how would you know it's a word? I click the link above and I see "Certificated, adjective." I have tried to scroll farther up, but the page won't  budge. So, I think that's the top. Because it's such a common word, in my original answer, I used the first  definition I found. Challenged, I searched for something more to the challenger's taste (Cambridge). Sorry.

Comment: @MicahWindsor BTW, are you familiar with the word "bluddle"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108694/discussion-between-zan700-and-micah-windsor).

Comment: The definition given in the answer is clearly for "certificate", not for "certificated": as has already been pointed out, the definition begins with "a document", it just makes no sense as a definition for "certificated". The definition you linked to in a comment actually is for "certificated", so you should [edit] your answer to use that definition.

Comment: @MicahWindsor - in the world of governments governing bodies, and authorizing organizations, “certified” and “certificated” have different legal connotations. For example, a pilot can be certified to fly specific aircraft or specific locations. This authorization can expire if specific step are not taken. A pilot’s certificate has no expiration date. So, a duly certificated pilot might not be certified to fly even when his/her certificate is still valid. Confusing, right?