# Can 'issuee' be used as 'employee' is used in respect to 'employer'?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I wonder if *issuee* is a word that can be used to indicate the other party, opposed to the *issuer*, in for example, a digital certificate issuing process? For example:

> The issuer of the certificate is LetsEncrypt, the issuee is SomeCompany Inc.

Comment: It's not in the OED or other dictionaries. But it's clear what it means, so you could use it and expect to be understood. There is a similar question, but it doesn't seem to have got any relevant answers https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/497434/how-would-you-call-a-person-who-posses-a-certificate

Comment: The word "subject" is usually used in PKI.